# Django valid form not saving

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently working in django and I am stuck for now. I have a form that has been validated but still not saving or in my case not have any data in it.

forms.py

```
class ConfirmForm(forms.ModelForm):

        c_no = forms.CharField(label="c_no", widget=forms.HiddenInput)

        helper=FormHelper()
        helper.form_method = 'Post' 
        helper.layout = Layout(

            Field('c_no'),



            Div(ButtonHolder(Button('cancel','Close', data_dismiss="modal", css_class='btn-default'),
                       Submit('yes', 'Yes', css_class='btn-success'),
                       Submit('no', 'No', css_class='btn-danger')

                                    ),
                       css_class='modal-footer')    
               )     
        class Meta:
            model = Complaint
            fields = ['c_no']
```

Views.py

```
elif 'yes' in request.POST:
                    rform = ConfirmForm(request.POST)
                    if rform.is_valid():
                            a = rform.save(commit=False)
                            c_no = a.c_no
                            b = Complaint.objects.get(c_no=c_no)
                            b.status = 3
                            b.save()
                            c = {}
                            c.update(csrf(request))

                            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

models.py

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   c_no = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
   Email = models.EmailField()
   Type = models.TextField()
   block = models.TextField()
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   location = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()
   status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.c_no)
```

Django POST data:

```
yes     u'Yes'
c_no    u'28'
```

Django local variables:

```
a   <Complaint: None>
c_no    None
rform   <register.forms.ConfirmForm object at 0xb281d34c>
```

As you can see, rform is getting the data but a and c_no variables are not getting anything. This means that rform is validated but not getting the data. 
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Could you also post your model?

Comment: What's the point of a form with only a single hidden field? (And that stuff you do with `c` is totally useless.)

Comment: I need the value of c_no in view from template, so I am pretty sure it's not useless.

Comment: But you're passing it from the view to the template in the first place, and then the form is passing it straight back to the view. It's hidden, so the viewer can't modify it. So what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = rform.save(commit=False)
```

`commit=False` means "hey form, update the model instance but do not actually save it in the database just yet, I got a few more things to do with it before saving it". When you pass `commit=False` to the form's `save` method, *you* are responsible to call `a.save()` at some later point — in your case it doesn't seem you're modifying the `a` instance any further, so I have no idea why you have the `commit=False` there in the first place. Since `a.c_no` is an `AutoField`, it will not be populated until the `a` instance is saved, but you explicitly forbid the form to save it, and you never save it yourself.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method